# GetJSON Returns 2 results for one posted value to PHP Script

Tags: php, jquery, json, mysqli

I am trying to use .getJSON to post one value to a url, and have it return all corresponding values for that one value.

All values are stored in a MySQL MyISAM table.

The request is:

```
$.getJSON('queries.php', { key: $("#cfkey").val()},  
function(result) {
$.each(result, function(i,r) {
    console.log("user:" + r.username + "Addr:" + r.addr);
    setItem("_cfuser", r.username);
    //console.log("user:" + r.username + "saved");
});
});
```

cfkey, is a unique key assiged to each "user", and the idea is to get this function to return only corresponding results to that key.

PHP Code:

```
//error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set("display_errors", 1);
include 'db/dbcon.php';
$input = $_GET['key'];
$input2 = $_GET['val'];
if($_GET) {
$q = "SELECT * FROM `cfaddrbook` WHERE '".$input."' = '".$input2."'";
} else {
$q = "SELECT * FROM `cfaddrbook`";
}
//Start connection with SQL
$res = $mysqli->query($q) or trigger_error($mysqli->error."[$q]");
$array = array(); // initialize
while($row = $res->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
 $array[] = array(
'key' => $row[0],
'username' => $row[1],
'password' => $row[2],
'nick'     => $row[3],
'addr'     => $row[4],
'facebook' => $row[5],
'twitter'  => $row[6],
'linkedin' => $row[7],
'youtube'  => $row[8]
// ... continue like this
);
}
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($array);
$res->free();
$mysqli->close();
```

**Currently, the function returns all usernames, and all addresses for one single key.** 
**I would like to send a request for a key, and get only corresponding data back, not other keys' data.
I would also like to be able to input queries?key= and get back corresponding data that way as well.**

**EDIT:**
Working code:

```
include 'db/dbcon.php';
$thekey = $_GET['key'];
$input = $mysqli->real_escape_string($thekey);
if($_GET) {
$q = "SELECT * FROM `cfaddrbook` WHERE `key` = ".$input."";
} else {
$q = "SELECT * FROM `cfaddrbook`";
}
//Start connection with SQL
$res = $mysqli->query($q) or trigger_error($mysqli->error."[$q]");
$array = array(); // initialize
while($row = $res->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
  $array[] = array(
'key' => $row[0],
'username' => $row[1],
'password' => $row[2],
'nick'     => $row[3],
'addr'     => $row[4],
'facebook' => $row[5],
'twitter'  => $row[6],
'linkedin' => $row[7],
'youtube'  => $row[8]
);
}
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($array);
$res->free();
$mysqli->close();
```

Comment: JavaScript isn't magically adding usernames to your JSON, so it sounds like your PHP code is returning the wrong data. Post the PHP.

Comment: Added the PHP code. I only want the ajax to return corresponding values to that key, not all the addresses and usernames for other keys.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to phrase it a way that sounded like an order. My apologies.

Comment: Be sure to sanitize your database input though! Make sure SQL Injection or any other exploit isn't possible. http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: I tried mysqli_escape_string for the $_GET variables, but it made them blank, and it gave a mysqli error in the error logs stating that the values were blank.

Comment: Figured out the escape problem. Please reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3005135/mysql-real-escape-string-just-makes-an-empty-string and the answer is by user @Panique

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have several problems.

1. `getJSON` sends a `GET` request, but you're trying to read from `$_POST`.
2. Even if it used `POST`, you're sending `cfkey` but reading `key` in your PHP code.
3. You're not doing any sort of escaping on the value, so this would open you to easy SQL injection.

Because of 1 and 2 specifically, your code isn't actually branching how you think it is, so it's running your "select everything" path instead of the "select one record" path.

Debugging tips for the future: Use Chrome or Firefox and watch the network activity - you can see if things are `GET` or `POST`, then add `var_dump` throughout your PHP dumping bits of data to make sure the values you think are getting in there are actually getting there.

Comment: If I use get JSON, and then change the PHP to if($GET) { and change the input variable to  input = $_GET, then the get json call says the server returned with a 500 error?

Comment: Would it be better to use .postJSON or something?

Comment: If you get a 500 error, chances are you typod something; what is your actual error? Can you check the error log? There's no such thing as `postJSON` but you can use `post` itself to do this.

Comment: PHP error: [01-Feb-2014 13:16:15 America/Denver] PHP Notice:  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'key = '111111'' at line 1[SELECT * FROM `cfaddrbook` WHERE key = '111111'] in path/engine/queries.php on line 12

Comment: [01-Feb-2014 13:16:15 America/Denver] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function fetch_array() on a non-object in path/engine/queries.php on line 14

Comment: Well there you go; you have an SQL error. Try escaping `key` with backquotes as well.

Comment: Updated the PHP. The code above does not return 500 errors, does not return mysql errors. It simply says key and val are undefined. If I replace input with just WHERE key =, and leave input 2, then I get SQL syntax errors like the ones above. Escaping the strings doesn't seem to help?

Comment: Actually, Escaping the string seems to make the value blank.

Comment: Figured how how to make the query work. I will update the page with working code. But I cannot figure out how to sanitize it without making the value blank. Any suggestions?

Comment: Figured it out, please reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3005135/mysql-real-escape-string-just-makes-an-empty-string and the answer is by user @Panique

Comment: I said to escape `key` not the value - literally the word `key` which is a reserved word in MySQL; i.e. `PRIMARY KEY`