# Weird issue where mysql_real_escape_string is returning blank

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I am creating a magento module and and in the controller I am trying to generate a query.
ex: `"INSERT INTO ". $resource->getTableName('mymod/mymodtable')." SET`pid`='".mysql_real_escape_string($pp['id'])."'";`
On my local setup this works ok, and I get the expected `id` in `pid`. But as soon as I upload it to my server, that portion becomes blank. I know that the database connection exists, because it inserts a new row with blank `pid` on server. I have tried `var_dump` and it does prove that `$pp['id']` has the value, yet `mysql_real_escape_string` returns blank. I also tried `mysqli_real_escape_string`, but nothing. Any ideas?

Comment: Any errors in your web server logs?

Comment: Now is a good time to update the code to placeholders! Although, it is a rather .. odd .. issue. *If* the reported behavior is accurate, the only think I can think of is that the server has either a *broken* or a *compromised* setup. What values of `$pp['id']` have been observed failing? Are you observing "the blank" immediately after the escaping (with `var_dump`)? Have some minimal code to reproduce/observe the behavior (and, can you post such a minimal test-case as an accurate copy'n'paste code block)?

Comment: @helion3 Nope, no errors

Comment: @user2864740 umm, since even I can't reproduce it outside the server, I cannot give a test block. But it's failing for any and all types of values in `$pp`, and even hardcoded values are failing.

Comment: @user279988 No, I mean, *I want to see* the actual code you're using (for both the mysql_ and mysqli_ form) to display and verify the results .. in a single consolidated block of code.

Comment: At least in old-history, mysql_real_escape_string was connection-independent and, as such, was just a simple text replacement function. I cannot find the source for it now, however, and I suspect that it now uses a connection. If it *does* use a connection, then one other possibility can be checked: *does it work "locally" when connecting to the "remote" database*?

Answer (score 0):

Which database interface are you using? `mysql_real_escape_string` should be used **only** with `mysql_query`, and you shouldn't be using that interface if you can avoid it. Without a valid connection it may not function correctly.

When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. Calling the escaping function manually is usually a mistake.

If you're using Magento, you might want to look at [how to escape values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11132797/how-to-mysql-escape-in-magento) using the Magento database layer.

Comment: I am using `mysql`, and `mysqli_real_escape_string` was just a test to rule out that condition. But what I don't understand is how does it work on my local setup, and not on server?

Comment: Are you using MySQL the database or `mysql_query` specifically? Magento has its own database layer you should be using whenever possible.

Answer (score 0):

Per this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3005135/mysql-real-escape-string-just-makes-an-empty-string), you probably don't have a "database connection".

What's often confusing is, that when the `mysql_real_escape_string` documentation talks about a database connection, they specifically mean a database connection opened with the [`mysql_connect`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) function.

If you're using Magento's standard objects to talk to the database, you don't have a `mysql_connect` connection, you have a [PDO connection](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (via a [`Zend_Db_Adapter` class](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.adapter.html)).  PDO is designed to encourage parameterized queries.

So, your options here

1. Go with the flow and build your queries using parameterized query strings.  (if you can't  figure out how a new questions with some code samples should set you right).
2. The adapter object has a [quote method](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.adapter.html) which you can use to quote your strings

Comment: Thanks, I tried to use prepared statements like `$writeConn->query($qry,array('id'=>$pp['id']))`, which works fine, but with this method alone I can't pass a string type value with many special characters like strings containing both single and double qoutes, so `mysql_real_escape_string` is basically my lazy-man's approach to saving exact values always. What is the alternative for magento if I want to write my queries manually?

Comment: @user279988 Yes, actually, you can.  The idea is the `query` function and bound parameters are automatically escaped for you. This way you don't need to worry about escaping them, the system handles it for you.  Give it a try.